# terrain collision system returning small height values

Tags: java, lwjgl

I'm trying to make a simple terrain collision system for my game, but
it's just returning small values ranging from 0.3 - 1, nothing higher or lower, and my character just stays at the same height.

I've been trying to fix this for hours, but I haven't found the solution yet.

Here is the code for collisions:

```
package terrain;


    public float getHeightOfTerrain(float worldx,float worldz) 
    {
        float terrainX = worldx - this.x;
        float terrainZ = worldz - this.z;
        float gridSquareSize = size - (float)(heights.length -1f);
        int gridx = (int)Math.floor(terrainX/gridSquareSize);
        int gridz = (int)Math.floor(terrainZ/gridSquareSize);
        if(gridx >= heights.length - 1 || gridz >= heights.length -1 || gridx<0||gridz<0) 
        {
            return 0;
        }
        float xCoord = (terrainX % gridSquareSize)/gridSquareSize;
        float zCoord = (terrainZ % gridSquareSize)/gridSquareSize;
        float answer;
        if (xCoord <= (1-zCoord)) 
        {
            answer = Mathc
                    .barryCentric(new Vector3f(0, heights[gridx][gridz], 0), new Vector3f(1,
                            heights[gridx + 1][gridz], 0), new Vector3f(0,
                            heights[gridx][gridz + 1], 1), new Vector2f(xCoord, zCoord));
        } else 
        {
            answer = Mathc
                    .barryCentric(new Vector3f(1, heights[gridx + 1][gridz], 0), new Vector3f(1,
                            heights[gridx + 1][gridz + 1], 1), new Vector3f(0,
                            heights[gridx][gridz + 1], 1), new Vector2f(xCoord, zCoord));
        }
        return answer;
    }
    private RawModel generateTerrain(Loader loader,String heightMap)
    {
        BufferedImage image = null;
        try
        {
            image = ImageIO.read(new File("res/"+heightMap+".png"));
        } catch (IOException e)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        int vertex_count = image.getHeight();
        heights = new float[vertex_count][vertex_count];
        int count = vertex_count * vertex_count;
        float[] vertices = new float[count * 3];
        float[] normals = new float[count * 3];
        float[] textureCoords = new float[count*2];
        int[] indices = new int[6*(vertex_count-1)*(vertex_count-1)];
        int vertexPointer = 0;
        for(int i=0;i<vertex_count;i++){
            for(int j=0;j<vertex_count;j++){
                vertices[vertexPointer*3] = (float)j/((float)vertex_count - 1) * size;
                float height = getheight(j,i,image);
                heights[j][i] = height;
                vertices[vertexPointer*3+1] = height;
                vertices[vertexPointer*3+2] = (float)i/((float)vertex_count - 1) * size;
                Vector3f normal = calculateNormal(j,i,image);
                normals[vertexPointer*3] = normal.x;
                normals[vertexPointer*3+1] = normal.y;
                normals[vertexPointer*3+2] = normal.z;
                textureCoords[vertexPointer*2] = (float)j/((float)vertex_count - 1);
                textureCoords[vertexPointer*2+1] = (float)i/((float)vertex_count - 1);
                vertexPointer++;
            }
        }
        int pointer = 0;
        for(int gz=0;gz<vertex_count-1;gz++){
            for(int gx=0;gx<vertex_count-1;gx++){
                int topLeft = (gz*vertex_count)+gx;
                int topRight = topLeft + 1;
                int bottomLeft = ((gz+1)*vertex_count)+gx;
                int bottomRight = bottomLeft + 1;
                indices[pointer++] = topLeft;
                indices[pointer++] = bottomLeft;
                indices[pointer++] = topRight;
                indices[pointer++] = topRight;
                indices[pointer++] = bottomLeft;
                indices[pointer++] = bottomRight;
            }
        }
        return loader.loadToVAO(vertices, textureCoords, normals, indices);
    }

    private float getheight(int x,int z,BufferedImage image) 
    {
        if(x<=0 || x>= image.getHeight()||z<=0||z>=image.getHeight()) 
        {
            return 0;
        }
        float height = image.getRGB(x,z);
        height += maxPixelColor/2f;
        height /= maxPixelColor/2f;
        height *= maxHeight;
        return height;
    }
}
```

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: Scary Wombat i just put a small part of my code so that won't help